# WordPress: how can i create a custom .php page that have another .php file link in it?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

im trying to create a custom page in WordPress i did some research and what you need to do is to create a .php file in the theme folder that include this code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: login */ ?>
```

this one php file that you include this cod in work great but in my case it's a registration form and it does have a link to another .php file which is register.php and when i try to go for that link it will say :"This page doesn't seem to exist" even though both .php files are in the same directory and i even tried to include full path in the link didn't work my full login.php file is like this:

```
<?php include('server.php') /* Template name: login*/ ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="login.php">

        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" >
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_user">Login</button>
        </div>
        <p>
            Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a><!-- problem is here -->
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on register it take me to :http://localhost/wordpress/login/register.php (login title of the page) and say it doesnt exist 
instead of opening the register.php file in the same directory

Comment: did you made the page in backend and set the custom template in it.

Comment: i did put the .php file in the theme folder and then the template name "login" show up to select when creating a page